# Rendering the content asynchronously in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, react-table

Basically I have a set of dynamic tables that are being displayed based on the values passed. If there is an empty array passed, it should show No data found. In my case when I send data to the table, all the tables will show "No data found" first then followed by the actual table content. I am not sure what is causing this.

The data is loaded asynchronously , it shows no data found and then the actual content. I have added setInterval to show this asynchronous nature

Sandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-ryiny?file=/src/index.js:0-1322

Can someone help me?

### Parent

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import DataGrid from "./DataGrid";

const d1 = [{ name: "test", age: "20" }, { name: "test1", age: "15" }];
const d2 = [{ area: "area", pin: "123" }, { area: "area1", pin: "1245" }];
const c1 = [
  { Header: "Name", accessor: "name" },
  { Header: "Age", accessor: "age" }
];
const c2 = [
  { Header: "Area", accessor: "area" },
  { Header: "Pin", accessor: "pin" }
];
const d3 = [];
const c3 = [];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data1: [],
      column1: [],
      data2: [],
      column2: [],
      data3: [],
      column3: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        data1: d1,
        column1: c1
      });
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        data2: d2,
        column2: c2
      });
    }, 2500);
    this.setState({
      data3: d3,
      column3: c3
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <DataGrid data={this.state.data1} columns={this.state.column1} />
        <DataGrid data={this.state.data2} columns={this.state.column2} />
        <DataGrid data={this.state.data3} columns={this.state.column3} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

### Child

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

export default class DataGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMore: false
    };
  }

  toggleState = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showMore: !prevState.showMore
    }));
  };

  formatData = () => {
    let arr = [];
    if (this.props.data && this.props.data.length > 0)
      arr = this.state.showMore ? this.props.data : this.props.data.slice(0, 2);
    return arr;
  };

  render() {
    const { showMore } = this.state;
    const { data, columns } = this.props;
    const showLink = data.length > 2;
    const subset = this.formatData();
    return (
      <>
        {showLink && (
          <button onClick={this.toggleState}>
            Show {showMore ? "Less" : "More"}
          </button>
        )}
        {data && data.length > 0 ? (
          <ReactTable
            showPagination={false}
            data={subset}
            columns={columns}
            minRows={0}
            NoDataComponent={() => null}
            loading={false}
          />
        ) : (
          "No data found"
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the App state's data with `null` instead of an empty array ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-x5bku?file=/src/index.js)):

```
this.state = {
  data1: null,
  column1: [],
  data2: null,
  column2: [],
  data3: null,
  column3: []
};
```

In the DataGrid `method` check if the value is falsy (`null` counts, but empty array is truthy), and return `null` (nothing to render) if it is:

```
render() {
  const { data, columns } = this.props;

  if (!data) return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding few points to the above answer.

The reason it was behaving in that way is not because of the asynchronous behavior but the  life-cycle nature of the React component.which in this case takes place as:

- The DataGrid is rendered with initial state of data i.e empty[] array.
- No data is shown because empty[] array is passed in this cycle.
- Then you are setting the state in componentDidMount.
- To show the effect Datagrid is again re rendered with actual data.